# How I can convert a blade content into PDF?

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

In my laravel project I have the following myview.blade.php content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ __('menu.title') }}</title>
</head>
<body>
 {{__('content') }}
</body>
```

But instead of rendering it into a http response, I want to be able to generate a pdf file out of it. Do you know How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a HTML to PDF library such as DOMPDF to do the actual conversion of HTML -> PDF

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

To get HTML from a blade view, you can do:

`$html = view('path/to/view', ['vars' => 'hello'])->render();`

Answer (score 1):

I used many solutions, including DOMPDF, but on average the output generated by WKHTMLTOPDF is far better than DOMPDF.

WKHTMLTOPDF follow CSS rules more precisely.

Well, wkhtmltopdf is a command line program that accepts an html file as parameter, so you just have to install it and you are ready to go. It has package for Linux and Windows.

**To the code**

Generate the desired html from your view, like this:

```php
$html = view('my_view', $arr);
```

Write the HTML to a temporary file:

```php
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'pdf_');
file_put_contents($temp_file, $html);
```

Run exec() on wkhtmltopdf:

```php
$pdf_file = $temp_file . '.pdf';
exec('wkhtmltopdf ' . $temp_file . ' ' . $pdf_file);
```

Download your `$pdf_file`.

Be happy.